# Error syncing Twitter Kit for android.

Tags: android, twitter, jar

I am trying to sync this in my build.gradle
  `// Twitter Kit
           compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
             }`

but i get the error : failed to find com.twitter.sdk.android.twitter:1.0.1

How do i import the twitter libraries correctly? i am lost